# Running the Graphic Modeler from the Python Console in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-python-console

How can I run the graphic modeler from the python console in QGIS?

Comment: Do you want to run **a model** from the graphic modeller from the python console, or just make the graphic model editor open up?

Answer (score 5):

- If you want how to run your own model with its parameters, first, open and run the model by Processing Toolbox. Then open `Processing > History` window and the last process shows how you can run the model. Select it and copy/paste into Python Console.

[image]

- If you want to open Graphical Modeler window by Python Console, try this:

  ```
    from processing.modeler.ModelerDialog import ModelerDialog
    dialog = ModelerDialog()
    dialog.show()
  ```

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions, but my models do not show up in the processing history. Other algorithms (e.g. native:...) do show up. Do you happen to know a reason for this?

Comment: I have no idea. My model appears in processing history after running the model. It may be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter:

```
import processing
processing.alglist()
```

In your python console you'll get a list of all available algorithms, and the appropriate syntax to call them. Models are just a kind of algorithms and you can run them with:

```
processing.runalg('modeler:modeler_name', arg1, arg2 ...)
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to add a new algorithm to the list of the algorithm?