# QGIS3 run model with python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I want to run a model with a python script, including the parameters, because I can't "translate" the model easily into a script.

I have tried to run a copy of the processing log after running the model, (from the console and the editor):

```
processing.run('model:myModel', {'form1':'P:/Form1.xlsx','form2':'P:/Form2.xlsx','form3':'P:Form3.xlsx','coordinatesystem':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:25832'),'native:mergevectorlayers_4:Border 1':'memory:','native:mergevectorlayers_6:Border 2':'memory:','native:mergevectorlayers_7:Cirlces':'memory:','qgis:createpointslayerfromtable_1:Baum':'memory:'})
```

Something happens, but the layers do not show up. I tried F5 but nothing changed.

I have found this piece of information, but it is for QGIS2

[How to run the graphic modeler from the python console in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299028/how-to-run-the-graphic-modeler-from-the-python-console-in-qgis)

How can I trigger the execution of a model with its parameters in pyGIS and get the layer window updated?

Comment: Try replacing `processing.run(...)` with `processing.runAndLoadResults(...)`

Comment: Thank you Joseph, that solved my problem! 
I got one more question which I believe is related to my original question:
What if the model is not yet part of the QGIS-project, but instead a file in some folder. How would I go about changing the 'model:myModel' into a file path?